# как установить задержку на анимацию?

Tags: android

Необходимо применить одну и ту же анимацию к двум виджетам с определенной задержкой, но применяемый мной метод setStartOffSet(delay) не дает желаемого результата. Что не так?

```
res/anim:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="750"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:duration="3000">
    </translate>
</set>

java:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mImage1;
    ImageView mImage2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_1);
        mImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_2);

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.trans_animation);

        mImage1.startAnimation(animation);
        animation.setStartOffset(1000); // НЕ РАБОТАЕТ ЗАДЕРЖКА?!
        mImage2.startAnimation(animation);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте создать отдельные объекты анимаций и им разные параметры задать:

```
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.trans_animation);
    mImage1.startAnimation(animation);

    Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.trans_animation);
    animation1.setStartOffset(1000);
    mImage2.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Comment: огонь, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `Thread.sleep();` вместо `animation.setStartOffset(1000);`Должно сработать.
Так:

```
mImage1.startAnimation(animation);
Thread.sleep(1000);
mImage2.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: К сожалению не сработало. Все время отведенное на "сон", почему-то, приложение использует до анимации.

Comment: Странно! А вы попробовали использовать `android:startOffset` в самом XML?

Comment: android:startOffset = "1000"

Comment: тогда мне придется для каждого View создавать файл.xml в папке anim (я не ленивый, просто, если есть метод setStartOffset()... и еще в моем проекте не 2, а 8 виджетов...)

Comment: Усыплять основной поток - плохая идея. Если усыпить надо будет на 5+с, то приложение выдаст ANR. Тем более, что усыпляя основной поток будут заморожены и все его операции, в т.ч. отрисовка интерфейса. Т.е. сразу после попытки начала первой анимации всё замрёт, а потом продолжит отрисовываться первая анимация и сразу стартует вторая. Т.е. по факту увидем то, то видит ТС - задержка на секунду и одновременное срабатывание обеих анимаций.

Comment: Вы не правильно поняли, startOffset в разметке с анимацией, например добавить в trans_animation.xml

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да я понимаю. Но это было как бы Решение в Лоб